# Calculating the regression coefficient of a time-based series

Tags: functions, regression, least-squares, slope

If i have a sample (lets say house price in millions over time) where x=1,2,...,14 samples y-values are shown in the image below, with one sample estimated per month.

How do i calculate the estimated increment per month? I figured it would be something with a simple regression formulas regression coefficient

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you assume $AR(1)$, i.e., $Y_t = \beta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, then you can use the usual OLS formulas where your $X$ is $Y_{t-1}$, namely 
$$
\hat{\beta}=\frac{\sum y_t y_{t-1} }{\sum y_t^2}.
$$
This estimator is biased, however consistent.